# Printing the PDF only if we set printer as default printer in C#.net

Tags: c#

The below code is used for print the PDF.

```
private void PrintReport(string printerName,string filePath)
        {

            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.Verb = "print";
            info.FileName = filePath;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.Arguments = printerName;

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/p {0}/h {1}", printerName, filePath);

            p.Start();


            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                p.Kill();

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }



        }
```

But it work only if the printer specified is a default printer.
Need to get print in any of the printer specified(printerName) .Can anyone tell me what will be the issue?